# Can a CSS background URL be passed a dynamic query string, and if so, how?

Tags: css, background

Is it possible to pass the `url` attribute a dynamical query string? E.g `url( ./SOME_IMAGE_GENERATOR?image=1 );` where `image` varies?

I need this attribute to be set via JS:

```
$( "#elem" )[ 0 ].style.background = "url( ./renders/circuit.php?circuit=" + dirY + dirX + "&dims=1|1 )";
```

The link in the `url` points to a file, that generates and returns an image.
The image is generated correctly, but not applied as backround.

**Clarification**

The image I want to put inside does not exist yet. It is generated and returned by the page `circuits.php` and depends on the arguments.

The background is well changed, if the image exists. I have noticed that unlike changin the `src` attribute of the `img` tag, while the argument creates a request by the browser, sends and recieves headers and info, the `background` does not.

I'd thought about sending a request to the `circuit.php` generator, make him save the image on the server and then, with `setTimeout`, change the background, but I cannot rely on a certain time for the generation.

That is the problem. Now, do you guys have any ideas how to overtake this?

Comment: Show us the relevant CSS, so that your question has some context.

Comment: Have you tried `style.backgroundImage`?

Comment: @MrSlayer I've made an update to the topic

Comment: could you post a link with working arguments to this image generator that we could use to test solutions with?
ie a full url

Comment: @DigitalBiscuits the file is on my local server. It returns a png file, size of 22x22 pixels, for a working argument and a blank transparent file of same size for other cases.

Comment: ok, and does it load the generated image into your background if you have the style already set in a stylesheet when the page loads?

Comment: interesting, sounds like an issue with your php script that's generating the image then. 
I've just created another answer, where I've demonstrated that you can dynamically use images that are generated with passed arguments (in my example its the colour of the image).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Working Example

I've replicated your scenario with a Jsfiddle and a image generating script held on my own website.

As you can see it is indeed possible to change the background dynamically with a generated image:
http://jsfiddle.net/DigitalBiscuits/Eh8yY/6/

## Debugging your code

So....what's wrong with yours?
Well firstly if you're using Firefox or Chrome, use the developer tools to check what's going on. Make sure no Javascript errors are showing up in the console.

Then I would suggest you check that your javascript is actually selecting the element, and that it is able to change the background (lets say to a static image). Isolate the code you that's giving you problems and test it out in a new empty page, kinda like the JSfiddle I've linked you to above.

On a side note,  your javascript code looks a bit foreign to me.

Instead of:

> ```
> $( "#elem" )[ 0 ].style.background = ...
> ```

try using:

> ```
> document.getElementById('myImg').style.background = ...
> ```

Lastly, ensure that you're setting the correct headers in your php script that generates the images, and that no output is happening before the headers are set.

Comment: I really don't know, why, but when I provided a full path (including "http://...") it worked. I'd already tried everything you wrote in **debuggin** before you posted it. P.S. in my script `$( "#elem" )[ 0 ] === document.getElementById('elem')`. Anyway, your answer solved the problem. V + 1. P.P.S Maybe, when the address is provided localy, like "./renders/..." the browser seeks in local directories and avoids sending headers. I guess, a full path makes the browser to open an HTTP reqeust. That's interesting.

Comment: how interesting...well as long as it works now, I guess that's the most important thing. Glad I could help you arrive at an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using jQuery?
This should be very easy to do.

Store the generated image url in a variable, and then use jQuery to change the CSS background image value, like so:

> ```
> var imageUrl = "./renders/circuit.php?circuit=" + dirY + dirX + "&dims=1|1";
> $('#myDiv').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
> ```

Here's a a jsfiddle demonstrating the concept. Click the `div` to see the background-image dynamically changed via JS.
http://jsfiddle.net/DigitalBiscuits/F3PUy/2/

Comment: I'm not usins jQuery. That's my own script. `$` is just very comfortable =) Please, read topics update.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible to set on-the-fly images as background images, using CSS.

This is no different to how you can use on-the-fly images for `img` elements.